# Update entity with EF exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I try to update an entity but I'm receiving this common exception:

> store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I have this code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Atualizar(TipoDocumentoViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return PartialView("_Atualizar", model);

        var entity = await DbContext.TipoDocumento.FirstAsync(x => x.ChaveExterna == model.Id);
        entity.Nome = model.Nome;
        var entry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        try
        {
            await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException uex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", @"Houve um erro ao tentar executar a ação. Tente novamente mais tarde.");
            return PartialView("_Atualizar", model);
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            AddErrors(ex.EntityValidationErrors);
            return PartialView("_Atualizar", model);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", @"Houve um erro ao tentar executar a ação. Tente novamente mais tarde.");
            return PartialView("_Atualizar", model);
        }

        return Json(new { });
    }
```

I don't know why I got this exception. I made the same thing in another controllers and works fine, but now, It doesn't want to work.

I try to not update the property and I'd the same exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I've interceptors to put data in audit columns and I don't know why It doesn't work here:

```
/// <summary>
///     Esse interceptor foi obtido desta url:
///     http://marisks.net/2016/02/27/entity-framework-soft-delete-and-automatic-created-modified-dates/
///     <para> Ele foi modificado para adicionar o ID do usuário e a data de Criação/Atualização/Exclusão</para>
///     Essas são as informações de auditoria que a aplicação é responsável em obter.
/// </summary>
public class EntityFrameworkAuditInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    private const string CreateUserColumnName = "UsuarioCriacaoId";
    private const string CreateDateColumName = "DataCriacao";
    private const string UpdateUserColumnName = "UsuarioEdicaoId";
    private const string UpdateDateColumnName = "DataEdicao";
    private const string DeleteUserColumnName = "UsuarioExclusaoId";
    private const string DeleteDateColumnName = "DataExclusao";
    private const string DeletedColumnName = "Deletado";

    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace != DataSpace.SSpace)
            return;

        if (interceptionContext.Result is DbQueryCommandTree queryCommand)
            interceptionContext.Result = HandleQueryCommand(queryCommand);

        else if (interceptionContext.Result is DbInsertCommandTree insertCommand)
            interceptionContext.Result = HandleInsertCommand(insertCommand);

        else if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult is DbUpdateCommandTree updateCommand)
            interceptionContext.Result = HandleUpdateCommand(updateCommand);

        else if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult is DbDeleteCommandTree deleteCommand)
            interceptionContext.Result = HandleDeleteCommand(deleteCommand);
    }

    private static DbCommandTree HandleInsertCommand(DbInsertCommandTree insertCommand)
    {
        var userId = Convert.ToInt32(((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).Claims
                                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value ?? "0");
        var setClauses = insertCommand.SetClauses
            .Select(clause => clause.UpdateIfMatch(CreateUserColumnName, DbExpression.FromInt32(userId)))
            .Select(clause => clause.UpdateIfMatch(CreateDateColumName, DbExpression.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now)))
            .ToList();

        return new DbInsertCommandTree(insertCommand.MetadataWorkspace, insertCommand.DataSpace,
            insertCommand.Target, setClauses.AsReadOnly(), insertCommand.Returning);
    }

    private static DbCommandTree HandleUpdateCommand(DbUpdateCommandTree updateCommand)
    {
        var userId = Convert.ToInt32(((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).Claims
                                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value ?? "0");
        var setClauses = updateCommand
            .SetClauses
            .Select(clause => clause.UpdateIfMatch(UpdateUserColumnName, DbExpression.FromInt32(userId)))
            .Select(clause => clause.UpdateIfMatch(UpdateDateColumnName, DbExpression.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now)))
            .ToList();

        return new DbUpdateCommandTree(updateCommand.MetadataWorkspace, updateCommand.DataSpace,
            updateCommand.Target, updateCommand.Predicate, setClauses.AsReadOnly(), null);
    }

    private static DbCommandTree HandleDeleteCommand(DbDeleteCommandTree deleteCommand)
    {
        var setClauses = new List<DbModificationClause>();
        var table = (EntityType)deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.EdmType;

        if (table.Properties.All(p => p.Name != DeletedColumnName))
            return deleteCommand;
        var userId = Convert.ToInt32(((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).Claims
                                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value ?? "0");

        setClauses.Add(DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(
            deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.Variable(deleteCommand.Target.VariableName)
                .Property(DeleteUserColumnName), DbExpression.FromInt32(userId)));
        setClauses.Add(DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(
            deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.Variable(deleteCommand.Target.VariableName)
                .Property(DeleteDateColumnName), DbExpression.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now)));
        setClauses.Add(DbExpressionBuilder.SetClause(
            deleteCommand.Target.VariableType.Variable(deleteCommand.Target.VariableName)
                .Property(DeletedColumnName), DbExpression.FromBoolean(true)));

        return new DbUpdateCommandTree(deleteCommand.MetadataWorkspace, deleteCommand.DataSpace,
            deleteCommand.Target, deleteCommand.Predicate, setClauses.AsReadOnly(), null);
    }

    private static DbCommandTree HandleQueryCommand(DbQueryCommandTree queryCommand)
    {
        var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new SoftDeleteQueryVisitor());
        return new DbQueryCommandTree(queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace, queryCommand.DataSpace, newQuery);
    }

    private class SoftDeleteQueryVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
    {
        public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
        {
            var table = (EntityType)expression.Target.ElementType;
            if (table.Properties.All(p => p.Name != DeletedColumnName))
                return base.Visit(expression);

            var binding = expression.Bind();
            return binding.Filter(binding.VariableType.Variable(binding.VariableName).Property(DeletedColumnName)
                .NotEqual(DbExpression.FromBoolean(true)));
        }
    }
}
```

But I use this in another systems and it works fine. I'll analyze why It doesn't work here.

**EDIT**

I found the reason, but I don't know why it's happining. I change the guid (external key) for int (pk) to search the row, and it works like a charm. It's strange, I will analyze this more to know what it doesn't work with guid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be (as it was in my project) with the `returning` parameter of the constructor of `DbUpdateCommandTree`. If you use `null` and you have computed columns (`HasDatabaseGeneratedOption`) on the entity, the update will fail and throw an `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

Try:

```
return new DbUpdateCommandTree(
    updateCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
    updateCommand.DataSpace,
    updateCommand.Target,
    updateCommand.Predicate,
    setClauses.AsReadOnly(),
    updateCommand.Returning);
```